# printing users input into an input field using php

Tags: php, html

how can I get users input and print it into another text field input?
I'm using php. I have 2 input types of text and one submit button. i want to be able to print the results of input A into the input textbox B
example:
        `<form>
        <input type="text" name="input"/> <!-- thiss is where the user enters text -->
        <input type="text" name="output"/> <!-- I take that text out and output it here -->
        <input type="submit" value="submit" <?php echo $input;/>
    </form>`
I keep trying to echo "$input" into output but not working.

Comment: show what you do .

Comment: always paste you code.

Comment: if you want that you type and it will display in another text field. than use js or its framework like angular

Comment: You cannot do this with PHP. PHP is a server-side language. There will need to be communication with the server. I suggest using javascript/jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with PHP since PHP is a server side language. It does not support client side manipulation.

You will need something like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('change', 'input[name="input"]', function () {
        var contents = $(this).val();
        $('input[name="outut"]').val(contents);
    })
});
</script>

<!-- HTML -->
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="input" />
    <input type="text" name="output" value="" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"> 
</form>
```

For more information about jQuery take a look at [this W3Schools article](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/)

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help

```
<?php
$output= (isset($_POST['submit']))?$_POST['input']:'';
?>
pure php. <br>
try to input value in input field then submit.
<form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="input"/> <!-- thiss is where the user enters text -->
        <input type="text" name="output" value="<?php echo $output;?>"/> <!-- I take that text out and output it here -->

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"> 
</form>


using javascript onchange.<br>try to input value in field input1
<form method="post">
        <input type="text" id="input1" name="input1" onchange="clone();"/> <!-- thiss is where the user enters text -->
        <input type="text" id="output1" name="output1" /> <!-- I take that text out and output it here -->

    <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="submit"> 
</form>

<script>
function clone()
{
     var x = document.getElementById("input1").value; document.getElementById("output1").value=x;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this what you are looking for using simple javascript events

```js
function myFunction(){
var a=document.getElementById('a').value;
 document.getElementById('b').value= a
 }
```

```html
<form>
        <input type="text" name="input"  onkeydown="myFunction()" onkeydown="myFunction()" id="a"/> <!-- thiss is where the user enters text -->
        <input type="text" name="output" id ="b"/> <!-- I take that text out and output it here -->
        <input type="submit" value="submit" >
    </form>
```